# Ruby square bracket setter/getter

Tags: ruby

Is it possible in Ruby to define such setters and getters for class that can be used with `[]` or `()` or smth alike? E.g.

```
word.meaning[:english] = "ruby"
puts word.meaning[:german] # "Rubin"
```

Note that `word.meaning` must not be a hash! and `:english`, `:german` are kind of additional parameters for setter/getter `meaning`.

Comment: How is `"Rubin"` derived from information `:english`, `"ruby"`, and `:german`? It is not clear at all what you are doing.

Comment: @sawa OP is asking for bracket "setter" and "getter" methods on a class instance. `word.meaning[:german] # "Rubin"` is an example of using the "getter" method.

Comment: Is "must not" meant to read "does not have to"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. You need to define a `[]=` and `[]` methods.

In this example, I am using a `Hash` as the internal data structure - you are free to use whatever you like.

```
class Word
  attr_reader :meaning

  def initialize
    @meaning = Meaning.new
  end
end

class Meaning
  attr_reader :h

  def initialize
    @h = {}
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    @h[key] = value
  end

  def [](key)
    @h[key]
  end
end
```

Example:

```
word = Word.new
word.meaning[:english] = 'Hello'
word.meaning[:english] # => 'Hello'
```

Comment: The OP clearly states `word.meaning must not be a hash` (although it is not clear why that has to be the case and what OP is doing). It seems like the OP is expecting the setter and the getter to not deal with exactly the same thing, but they are related in some way. I don't think you understood the question. Neither do I.

Comment: @sawa and my object is not a hash. `word.meaning` could be an instance of anything - `Foo` for example. **The hash in my example is purely an implementation detail.** As for understanding the question - I do understand it. OP could easily implement the getter to check for an `:english` key and translate to `:german`

Comment: It is just a wrapper around a hash. I believe what you did is precisely what OP does not want to do.

Comment: `check for an :english key and translate to :german` yes, I think that is what OP is implying. But it is not clear at all how that translation is done. Your answer does not give a clue to how the translation is done either.

Comment: @sawa OP is not asking for the details of translating missing keys - OP wants to know how to use bracket methods on an object instance. I believe my answer does just that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi @Kyle, this is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks, very cool